# Can't load a lot of websites since Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: google-chrome, 15.04

Since I upgraded to 15.04, almost all my websites now just sit there and load to a error message in Google Chrome.

I used to be able to get to Google.com now it just sits and loads to nothing. Ubuntu 14.10 had no issues loading sites up and now I do on 15.04?

Any help is welcome at this point because I'm getting a little mad about.

Edit: alright, now Google.com works but newegg.com is still not loading.
Edit2: Youtube loads but no videos play

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. Non of my browsers on Ubuntu wanted to load specific websites, but at the same time on Windows everything worked just fine.

I reseted my rooter (turn off and on), and now all sites are working properly.